# Tab State Control AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

So I am relatively new to AngularJs and I am trying to figure out the best way for a tabController to remember what tab was previously clicked when switching to a new controller. So the situation would be I have 3 tabs. I click on tab 3 and then I click on something inside of it bringing me to a new controller and HTML template... What is the best way if I hit a "back" Button I created in that controller to remember exactly the state of it being the 3 tab.

I tried using $rootScope and then in each controller setting the tab number and setting the tabcontroller = $rootScope... but that was chaotic and too repetitive.

Comment: You can go for local storage as well.

Comment: Angular localstorage bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my "HACKY" answer is to use $rootScope and at the main controller aka Tab 1 have if statements to determine the tab... seems to work.